# Access a variable in Django cron.py from other modules

Tags: python, django, cron

I defined a variable in urls.py which will be updated every 10 seconds from views.py. I am trying to access this variable in cron.py, I need the updated value when I called from cron.py but I am getting the intialised value but not the updated one.

Comment: Show us a minimal reproducible example!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. That variable is read only when Django is initializing.

Plus servers normally use multiple Django workers and each one of those will have a different instance for that variable.

You need to use something like Redis to save the variable to RAM or disk(if you need persistance).